# Multiple APKs packaging the same library can cause runtime errors with only one dynamic module on AGP 4.0.1?

Tags: android, modularity, android-app-bundle, dynamic-feature-module

I have only one dynamic feature module in my project called search, But when I try to build project, I get that Error:

```
    [:search, :search] all package the same library [androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview].
    
    Multiple APKs packaging the same library can cause runtime errors.
    Placing each of the above libraries in its own dynamic feature and adding that
    feature as a dependency of modules requiring it will resolve this issue.
    Libraries that are always used together can be combined into a single feature
    module to be imported by their dependents. If a library is required by all
    feature modules it can be added to the base module instead.
```

Of Course, the first thing I did is to research about people who had the same problem And I found:

1- [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58394717/android-dynamic-feature-modules-dependencies)
2- [This medium article](https://medium.com/pulselive/a-quick-look-at-feature-on-feature-dependencies-in-android-gradle-plugin-4-0-0-5828915d02d3)

Both Introduce the same solution (Use Android Gradle Plugin 4.0) and my project uses AGP 4.0.1, But the problem is that I have only one dynamic module called search. I don't have any other dynamic modules, even further I don't have the dependency of RecyclerView: `androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview` in my search gradle file, So this is maybe a transitive dependency.

Also, you can find that duplicated dependency in one of two ways:

1-Navigate to: PROJECT_NAME/module_name(In my case: search)/build/intermediates/

and then search for "deps.txt" file in that directory, Open the file and you will see all your module dependencies direct and transitive ones

2- run ./gradlew :module_name:dependencies task

If you tried to remove that duplicated line: `androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview` from "deps.txt" file, it gets generated again after each build.

That being said, I need some rule in my `packagingOptions {}` like `exclude` to prevent that conflict between `search.aar` and and any other `search.*` format

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: In my case,  Gradle is giving me an error of libraray ``` implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0' ``` I removed this library in one of feature modules, sync project, this resolve my error.
 remove ``` androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview ``` from feature module, I hope your error will resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I removed the below from one of the modules

> Note: not from the base module

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```